# Get Wordpress Title Without something

Tags: php, wordpress

I dont know If I can explain myself properly but I want to get the title but without something, for example:

The title is: "Recipie: Orange Juice" and I get it with this

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

And I want to get just "Orange Juice" 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace 'Recipie:' with empty string like this way

```
<?php
$title = get_the_title();
$title = str_replace( $title, 'Recipie:','');

echo $title;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this:

```
<?php
// Get the title.
$title = get_the_title();

// Replace leading prefix and colon if one exists.
$title = preg_replace('/^[^:]+\:\s*/', '', $title);

// Output the title.
echo $title;
```

Comment: sorry but how I introduce the "Recipie" in that?

Comment: @MauricioVilla The above will get rid of a leading `Prefix:`, so whether that is `Recipe:` or `Something:` else, the above will remove it for you. if you want to be more specific, you can change `[^:]+` to `Recipe`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Jason Caldwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219741/jaswrks)'s answer, here is `the_clean_title` function:

```
function the_clean_title($post_id = null) {
    // get the title.
    $title = get_the_title($post_id);

    // replace leading prefix and colon if one exists.
    $title = preg_replace('/^[^:]+\:\s*/', '', $title);

    // output the title.
    echo $title;
}
```

the usage is same as for `the_title` function, just replace your `the_title` calls with `the_clean_title` in source code:

```
the_clean_title();
```

Comment: sorry but how I introduce the "Recipie" in that?